# Illustrator/Photoshop Brush as Freestyle Line Set

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I've bought a couple of illustrator and Photoshop brushes for a project and I have been playing around with Freestyle but I was wondering if I could use the same brushes for the Line Set instead of using the standard ones. I came across some things, but not directly linked to my issue/idea.